# Do not fail on missing column in a SQLLite query

Tags: sqlite

I have a simple query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE CUSTID LIKE '~' AND BANKNO LIKE '~'
```

The problem is, the customers-table might or might not contain the BANKNO column depending on circumstances I've no control over. If however BANKNO is not a column in CUSTOMERS, this query fails.

So my question is: it is possible to test if the BANKNO column exists and if so, to include it in the query and if not to exclude this column?

The query really has to be flexible.

Answer (score 2):

A non-existent column in a SELECT to sqlite3 will always fail.

One option might be to put the "full" sql in a `try` block, and if it errors, execute the other sql.

Or, you could query `PRAGMA table_info('CUSTOMERS')` and interrogate the result to see if a column in question is in the database. Find the sqlite doc here https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_table_info.

I'm sure there are other options, but the bottom line is you need to know before the sql is executed that it contains only valid column names.

Comment: So if I understand this correctly, you could use PRAGMA table_info and then programatically parse the results, but you can't use the PRAGMA table_info results directly in the query. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that is how I understand it too.